# Ramda R.pickBy R.identity including zeros 0's

Tags: javascript, optimization, ramda.js

Simple question, how can I pipe a pickBy identity and include props with value of zero. Currently this example would omit zeroes

```
let linkType = { 
    name: 'zac',
    money: 0,
    problems: 'as much as the money'
}
let linksList = R.pipe(
                    R.pickBy(R.identity),
                  )(linkType);
```

Comment: Note that the call to `pipe` here is not necessary.  Perhaps this is the beginning of a longer pipeline of work, but as presented, you could just do `pickBy`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [R.either](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#either) with [R.equal(0)](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#equals) to get `true` if value equals 0, and the result of [R.identity](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#identity) if not:

```js
const linkType = {
  name: 'zac',
  money: 0,
  problems: 'as much as the money',
  another: false
}

const linksList = R.pickBy(R.either(R.equals(0), R.identity))(linkType);

console.log(linksList);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```